# How to implement an event which can be canceled?

Tags: c#, .net, events

Help me to implement an event, which handler can cancel it.

```
public class BuildStartEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public bool Cancel { get; set; }
}

class Foo
{
    public event EventHandler<BuildStartEventArgs> BuildStart;

    private void Bar()
    {
        // build started
        OnBuildStart(new BuildStartEventArgs());
        // how to catch cancellation?
    }

    private void OnBuildStart(BuildStartEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.BuildStart != null)
        {
            this.BuildStart(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use the already existing System.CancelEventArgs class?

Comment: I will, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574849/how-to-impement-an-event-which-can-be-canceled/574858#574858

Comment: btw, it's System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to modify this code:

```
private void Bar()
{
    // build started
    OnBuildStart(new BuildStartEventArgs());
    // how to catch cancellation?
}
```

to something like this:

```
private void Bar()
{
    var e = new BuildStartEventArgs();
    OnBuildStart(e);
    if (!e.Cancel) {
      // Do build
    }
}
```

Classes in .NET have reference semantics, so you can see any changes made to the object the parameter of the event references.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it would be much harder

Comment: Not everything in programming is difficult... it just seems that way :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your `BuildStartEventArgs` are redundant, the framework already offers the [`CancelEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.aspx) class – consider using it.

Comment: Thanks for tip. But my class has additional properties, I just didn't wrote them here.

Comment: But you can inherit from CancelEventArgs!

Answer (score 1):

Have a boolean Cancel property on the BuildStartEventArgs class.
Let the event handler(s) be able to flag this.

```
private void Bar()
{
  // build started
  var args = new BuildStartEventArgs();
  OnBuildStart(args);
  if (args.Cancel)
  {
    // cancel
  }

}
```

Comment: There is already a boolean Cancel property on the BuildStartEventArgs class in the example in the question.